# Redirect two or more STDOUT to a single STDIN

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I would like to redirect the output of two programs to a single STDIN pipe, possibly in the most efficient way possible.

Is that possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far and it's not clear what your input is and what your output is.

Comment: Are your 2 programs running in parallel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

```
{ command1 ; command2 ; } | command3
```

Comment: So basically create a third program that has the first two running in background and redirects it's output. Makes a lot of sense, I should have thought of it. Thank you.

Comment: Is it recognizable for `command3`? I mean what is order of piping. Is it a first and second scenario or they go through each other?

Comment: @muradin: The command grouping assures that `command1` and `command2` both use the same stdout.

Comment: @cedivad: Nothing is running in the background in Ignacio's answer. The braces `{` and `}` enclose a _group command_. See the bash man under `Compound Commands`.

Comment: Yes, I confused `;` with `&`. Replacing them did the trick anyway. It created another problem, and I ended up using a completely different solution, but did what was asked in the question.