# Separate STDIN between parent and child process

Tags: perl, unix, io, stdin

[Redirect two or more STDOUT to a single STDIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948350/redirect-two-or-more-stdout-to-a-single-stdin)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams says "More generally, a child process will inherit the standard streams of its parent process."

I am assuming if a child process close stdin then parent's stdin gets closed as well and not gettin any user input for code such as :

```
if ($select->can_read(1)) {
    my $char = getc();
    if (defined $char) {
        print ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> $char\n";
    }
}
```

Can a parent process have its own STDIN separate from child process' STDIN so that a child process can do whatever it wants with STDIN and parent's STDIN does not get affected?

Comment: If you think about it - where would the 'other' STDIN be coming from? How would you differentiate? But you could use a pipe or different filestream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I am assuming if a child process close stdin then parent's stdin gets closed as well*

No, the child gets a clone of the handle.

```
$ echo -n 'abcdefghijkl' | perl -e'
   sub r { sysread(STDIN, my $buf, 3); $buf }  # Unbuffered read.
   if (fork()) {
      print "Parent: $_\n" for r();
      sleep(2);
      print "Parent: $_\n" while $_ = r();
   } else {
      sleep(1);
      print "Child: $_\n" for r();
      close(STDIN);
      print "Child: Closed STDIN\n";
   }
'
Parent: abc
Child: def
Child: Closed STDIN
Parent: ghi
Parent: jkl
```

> *Can a parent process have its own STDIN separate from child process' STDIN so that a child process can do whatever it wants with STDIN and parent's STDIN does not get affected?*

Yes. For example, `foo <file` sets the `foo`'s STDIN rather than having it inherit its parent's.

Answer (score 3):

The child process gets *duplicates* of the parent's standard handles — they are copies, and not the same handle. That means the child can close its `STDIN` and reopen it as you wish, and you will not affect the parent process at all.